# How can I make an soundsystem with Slick?

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick

My question would be, how can I develop an easy-to-use sound system under slick-util?
Under the function

`a.playAsSoundEffect(1, 1, true, x, y, z);`

it already works to create a static position for the source. But if I adjust my CameraPosition in-game. So how can I change the position of the listener in Slick?

Answers would be awesome :)
Thanks,
Mineorbit!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the slick-util documentation, it doesn't look like there's a way to just change the x, y, and z positions while a sound is playing. The following is a work-around I could think of off the top of my head, but I don't know how efficient this would be

So, every time the camera position changes (or maybe only when the camera position has changed significantly,) store `a.getPosition()` in some variable (like `lastPosition`) to save where the sound was playing from. Then call `a.stop()`, `a.playAsSoundEffect(1, 1, true, new_x, new_y, new_z)`, and then `a.setPosition(lastPosition)`.

Again, not sure how efficient that would be, but it's an idea.

Comment: Thank you verymuch. this might be the obvious solution, but then i had to calculate the positional translatations in perspective of the camera myself, right? 'cause that was the thing I tried to avoid. if I can't figure this out, could somebody send me an easy tutorial link towards openal and an source and  listener system. The one on the lwjgl wiki I allready viewed and couldn't get into it. Again thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, you would have to calculate the translations yourself in this example. I'm not aware of any tutorials specifically for this situation, but I would imagine it's not too hard to figure out.